# Vs code não mostra os erros sublinhados!

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Meu Visual studio code, não esta mostrando os erros, enquanto estou programando, pode ser o erro mais simples que tiver. Antes ele sublinhava os erros, agora só mostra depois de executar o código. Já procurei em todo lugar, e não achei nada que funcionasse, alguém teria uma ideia de como resolver?
Eu programo em C.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu programo em **JavaScript**, e lá, para ter os erros sublinhados eu utilizo a extensão **ESLint**,talvez você precise duma extensão destas para C. ***Editado**:*
Achei uma extensão chamada "clangd" que compila erros e adiciona conclusão de código, entre outras coisas. Vê se supre sua necessidade.

Answer (score -2):

Eu programo em JavaScript, e lá, para ter os erros sublinhados eu utilizo a extensão ESLint, que é uma ferramenta de análise de código. Existe a extensão chamada "clangd" para C, que compila erros e adiciona conclusão de código, entre outras coisas. Vê se supre sua necessidade.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Valeu funcionou mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz, João! Coloca minha resposta como a correta, para dar fim ao tópico. Valeu!